# Why Can't I Access the Response (eg. to Check Response Code) When I Get a 429 With a Fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

If I do:

```
fetch(someUrl)
  .then(logResponse)
  .catch(logError);
```

and I get rate-limited (ie. the response has a 429 code), I *don't* go into the `then` (I can see that`logResponse` is never run).

Instead I go straight to the `catch` block, and it just gets passed an extremely simple error object with a name/type/message and nothing else (`TypeError: Failed to fetch`).

How can I access the `response` that came back (eg. so I can recognize, programmatically, the `429`)?

Comment: What error messages in the browser logging in the devtools console?

Comment: Access to fetch at '*someUrl*' from origin '*someUrl*' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: OK yeah, so if the 429 error lacks the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header, then the fetch will fail and your code would hit that `catch` block. But if instead the 429 error had the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header, then the fetch should not fail and you should instead be able to programatically recognize the 429 error and handle it.

Comment: Yes, it does lack the CORS header.  But does that mean that on a 429 without CORS header it's *impossible* for Javascript to access the `response`?  Because all the `catch` block gets passes is that (very minimal) `Error` object, not a `response`.  If so, that would absolutely qualify as a valid answer to this question.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful

Comment: Yes, if the response lacks the CORS header, then it does mean that on a 429 without a CORS header it's impossible for Javascript to access the response. In the case, the only information that the browser exposes to JavaScript programatically is that the fetch failed, for some reason not disclosed to your code.

Comment: I wrote an answer since you seemed to want to stay in the comments section, but if you submit your own answer I'll happily give you credit (and delete mine).

Answer (score 0):

As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful:

> A fetch() promise will reject with a TypeError when a network error is encountered or CORS is misconfigured on the server-side, although this usually means permission issues or similar — a 404 does not constitute a network error, for example.

This means (and @sideshowbarker confirmed in comments) that it is impossible to access the response details on this class of errors.  The best one can do is `.catch`, and then assume *some sort of networking issue* (like a CORS-denying rate-limiting API, but possibly something else) is to blame.

It seems odd, but evidently it's impossible to ever know that you got a 429 when you get a 429 ... unless the response has CORS headers on it.